# ASP.NET Core [Authorize] attribute allowing non-authed users to load a page

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-authorization

I have an ASP.NET Core Blazor app that uses Identity. This is set up in `Program.cs` as follows...

```cs
builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options => {
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
    // Password options skipped for brevity
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
  })
  .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();

//... further down...

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

There is also code to add some users which I don't think is relevant, as they are added fine.

I can log in and out as expected, and if I use code like this on a Blazor page...

```cs
  [Inject]
  public AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider { get; set; } = null!;

  private ClaimsPrincipal _me = null!;

  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() =>
    _me = (await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()).User;
```

...then I can check if the current user is logged in by checking `_me?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated`.

This correctly identifies if the user is authed or not.

Now I want to secure a page, so only a logged-in user can see it. I added an attribute at the top of the code file...

```cs
[Authorize]
public partial class UserList {
  // rest of the class omitted for clarity
```

However, I can still access this page, even when not logged in. If I add the code to create `_me` as above, then it shows me that I'm not logged in, but still allows access to the page. I tried adding the attribute to the .razor file as follows...

```cs
@page "/users"
@attribute [Authorize]
```

...but it didn't make any difference.

Anyone able to see what I've done wrong? Not sure if I've posted all the code you need, so if I missed anything, please let me know.

Comment: Hope this [link](https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/blazor/blazor-authorize-attribute/) can help you solve this issue.

Comment: @XinranShen Thanks, that was exactly the problem! If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Hi @DreamingOfSleep, I have updated an answer. Thank you for accpeting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `App.razor` file, use `AuthorizeRouteView` component instead of `RouteView` component.

```
<AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
```

More information please refer to [link](https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/blazor/blazor-authorize-attribute/).